# Using UIImagePickerController with a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, scrollview

I'm working on a piece of code with the logic bellow :

```
- On every tap on a button, a new view opens and allows the user to choose an image from the phone's gallery.
- The chosen image should be loaded and displayed in an horizontal scroll view.
```

The problem that I'm facing is that the picker dismisses fine when an image is selected, but the image does not load inside the UIcollectionView on picker dismiss (the placeholder image remains and is not replaced by the selected image). No crashes or errors are occurring in my console. Thanks for any help!

Here is my view controller for this feature :

```
public class ImagePickerViewController: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var mediaArray = [UIImage]()

    @IBAction func galleryButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.delegate = self

        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Gallery image", message: "Choose an image from your gallery", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) in
            imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            self.present(imagePickerController,animated: true, completion: nil )

        }))

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

        self.present(actionSheet, animated: true,completion: nil)

    }

    public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage

        mediaArray.append(selectedImage)


        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    public func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }



    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return mediaArray.count
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MediaCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MediaCollectionViewCell

        cell.mediaContent.image = mediaArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }



}
```

here is a part of my horizontal scroll view 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reload your collectionview when image get's selected.

```
public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage

        mediaArray.append(selectedImage)


        picker.dismiss(animated: true) {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer ^^